How to make argparse work nicely with enums and default values?
I have an enum:
from enum import auto, Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()

and I want to use it as an argument with argparse. To be more specific, I want to create an argument that accepts one of the enum names ("one", "two", "three") and possibly has a default value, and the corresponding enum member is stored in the namespace. In other words, I want to do something like this:
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from enum import auto, Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()


enum_map = {e.name.lower(): e for e in MyEnum}

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--enum",
    default="two",
    choices=tuple(enum_map.keys()),
    help="An enum value (Default: %(default)s)",
)
args = parser.parse_args()
args.enum = enum_map[args.enum]
print(args.enum)

This is some boilerplate code, and I wanted to eliminate it using a custom action. I took inspiration from this SO answer, and got the following example:
from argparse import Action, ArgumentParser, FileType, Namespace
from collections.abc import Callable, Sequence
from enum import auto, Enum
from typing import Any


class EnumAction[T](Action):
    _enum: type[T]
    _enum_map: dict[str, T]

    def __init__(
        self,
        option_strings: Sequence[str],
        dest: str,
        nargs: int | str | None = None,
        const: Any = None,
        default: str | T = None,
        type: Callable[[str], T] | FileType | None = None,
        choices: Sequence[T] | None = None,
        required: bool = False,
        help: str | None = None,
        metavar: str | tuple[str, ...] | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        if type is None:
            raise ValueError("type must be assigned an Enum when using EnumAction")
        if not issubclass(type, Enum):
            raise TypeError("type must be an Enum when using EnumAction")
        if choices is not None:
            raise ValueError("Can't specify choices when using EnumAction")

        self._enum = type
        type = None
        self._enum_map = {e.name.lower(): e for e in self._enum}
        choices = tuple(self._enum_map.keys())
        super().__init__(
            option_strings,
            dest,
            nargs,
            const,
            default,
            type,
            choices,
            required,
            help,
            metavar,
        )

    def __call__(
        self,
        parser: ArgumentParser,
        namespace: Namespace,
        values: str | Sequence[Any] | None,
        option_string: str | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self._enum_map[values])


class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()


parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "--enum",
    action=EnumAction,
    type=MyEnum,
    default="two",
    help="An enum value (Default: %(default)s)",
)
print(parser.parse_args())

It works quite well except for one problem: if I call the program without the --enum argument, I get the default value "two", but it isn't processed by my action so I get the string itself and not the enum member:
$ python demo.py --enum one
Namespace(enum=<MyEnum.ONE: 1>)

$ python demo.py
Namespace(enum='two')

The easiest fix is to set the default value to default=MyEnum.TWO instead of "two" or make my action convert the default parameter into the corresponding enum member if it's a string. However, this causes the enum member to show up in the help message which isn't very readable (and is the reason I set choices to the names of the members instead of the actual members):
$ python demo.py -h
usage: demo.py [-h] [--enum {one,two,three}]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --enum {one,two,three}
                        An enum value (Default: MyEnum.TWO)

How can I get an enum member in the namespace both when passing an argument and when using the default value, and see the member's name in the help message instead of the member itself?

The question is interesting and I don't know if it's possible without using an alternative to ArgumentParser but the proposed solution to the problem seems way overthought - why not just accept the string argument and validate/convert it on demand?

As I said, this results in some boilerplate I’d rather avoid (Imagine I have multiple enum arguments like this and each one needs its own mapping). Besides, this looks like something argparse should handle. I think it’s natural to have this behavior when the argument is an enum.

An alernative (or adjunct) to choices is type.  Define such function that converts strings to the enums. Remaining string defaults are passed through the type at the end of parsing.

But without choices I won’t see the possible values in the help message. If I use type, then the values of choices must also be that type, which again makes the help message less readable.

Here is my approach: Create a function enum_action(), which takes an enum class and return an custom argparse.Action class.
Code
# main.py
from argparse import Action, ArgumentParser
from enum import Enum, auto

class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()

class Color(Enum):
    Red = auto()
    Green = auto()
    Blue = auto()

def enum_action(enum_class):
    class EnumAction(Action):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            table = {member.name.casefold(): member for member in enum_class}
            super().__init__(
                *args,
                choices=table,
                **kwargs,
            )
            self.table = table

        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.table[values])

    return EnumAction

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--enum", action=enum_action(MyEnum), default=MyEnum.TWO)
parser.add_argument("--color", action=enum_action(Color), default=Color.Red)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

Sample interactions
$ python3 main.py -h
usage: main.py [-h] [--enum {one,two,three}] [--color {red,green,blue}]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --enum {one,two,three}
  --color {red,green,blue}

$ python3 main.py
Namespace(enum=<MyEnum.TWO: 2>, color=<Color.Red: 1>)

$ python3 main.py --enum one --color green
Namespace(enum=<MyEnum.ONE: 1>, color=<Color.Green: 2>)

$ python3 main.py --enum two --color blue
Namespace(enum=<MyEnum.TWO: 2>, color=<Color.Blue: 3>)

Notes

As stated, the function enum_action() takes in an enum class as parameter
It then created a custom class with a set of choices
For the choices= named argument, we can pass any iterable, not just list, but also dictionaries (the keys will be used)
The function enum_action() works for any number of enum classes, in this case, I showed that it works for MyEnum and Color
Note that the default for add_argument will be the actual enum (e.g. MyEnum.TWO) instead of a string ("two")


I think you are over complicating this.  You can use the choices to valid the allowed inputs, and then just swap out the value after running parse_args()
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from enum import auto, Enum


class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()


parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--enum', 
    default='two', 
    choices=[e.name.lower() for e in MyEnum], 
    help="An enum value (Default: %(default)s)",
)

args = parser.parse_args()
args.enum = MyEnum[args.enum.upper()]


The reason I use a dictionary instead of upper() is that upper case enum members is just a convention and if someone defines a member MyEnum.Four, then your solution breaks.

In Python, the readable string representation of an object is defined by __str__(self). Therefore, you can add the following method to your Enum class:
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.lower()

This way, even if you specify a MyEnum object as the default for add_argument() (i.e., default=MyEnum.TWO), the help message will display the value returned by __str__(self).
